# Java: Calling a base class function which is overriden,using object of inherited class?

Tags: java, overriding

In the following code snippet

```
class Shape   {
    public void area()   {
        System.out.println("This is Shape");
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape  {
    @Override
    public void area()   {
        System.out.println("This is Rectangle");
    }
}

class Main   {
    public static void main(String[] args)   }
        Shape rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.area(); 
        // Can i force java to call Shape's area instead of Rectangle's area
        // This is possible in C++ if the function is not virtual.
    }
}
```

Can i force java to call Shape's area instead of Rectangle's area ?

EDIT : No, But why has Java overlooked this feature, something that is not as dangerous as pointers ?

Comment: Rectangle extends Shape u forget?

Comment: I don't think it is a feature that is overlooked. In C++ when you omit the virtual keyword you essentially break polymorphism. Polymorphism is a pretty important part of OO and I more wonder why you would want a C++ function that is not virtual

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot.

Method invocation in java is based on the actual type of the object you are calling. In this case you are calling the object of actual type Rectangle, and therefore invoked area() method is the one from Rectangle.

If you need to use shape area() method, you would need to create an object of actual type Shape. Otherwise you would never be able to invoke area() method in Shape. Reflection in java might help in creating these since you are constructing a more general type from a specific type.

Answer (score 0):

No ways, but by changing your super and sub class method static you can achieve.

```
public static void area(){
  // Your code here
}
```